# Snakemake: using regex in expand()

Tags: python, regex, snakemake

I'm struggling with using regular expressions when using the expand function. For some reason, the wildcards are always imported as plain text instead of executed regular expressions. Whether the regex is introduced as a wildcard priorly or in connection to the expand function does not make a difference (see all_decompress vs. all_decompress2). The error is always:

```
Missing input files for rule DECOMPRESS:
Resources/raw/run1_lane1_read[1,2]_index\d+-\d+=[1-9], [11-32].fastq.gz
```

-

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

###### WILDCARDS #####

## General descriptive parameters
read = "[1,2]"
index_prefix = r"\d{3}-\d{3}"
index = r"[1-9], [11-32]"

##### RULES #####

### CONJUNCTION RULES ("all") ###
# PREANALYSIS #
rule all_decompress:
    input:
        expand("Resources/decompressed/read{read}_index{index_prefix}={index}.fastq", read=read, index_prefix=index_prefix, index=index)

rule all_decompress2:
    input:
        expand("Resources/decompressed/read{read}_index{index_prefix}={index}.fastq", read=[1,2], index_prefix=r"\d{3}-\d{3}", index=r"[1-9], [11-32]")

### TASK RULES ###
# PREANALYSIS #

# Decompress .gz zipped raw files
rule DECOMPRESS:
    input:
        "Resources/raw/run1_lane1_read{read}_index{index_prefix}={index}.fastq.gz"
    output:
        "Resources/decompressed/read{read}_index{index_prefix}={index}.fastq"
    shell:
        "gzip -d -c {input} > {output}"
```

Comment: Some  things that could be useful: `wildcard_constraints` (https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#wildcards) and `glob_wildcards` (https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html#glob-wildcards)

Comment: Maybe I didn't look carefully enough, but it seems to me that you `import re` without using it.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm right the function expand in Snakemake makes a list of strings. This function is used for filenames just like you used it.

I don't know if the expand function can be associated with regex to create the list.

But you can produce this list in python and give it to the rule all or the expand function.

In your case you can use the following code to get and make your liste of filenames :

```
import re
import os

path='.'
listoffiles=[]
for file in os.listdir(path):
  if(re.search('read[1-2]_index\d{3}-\d{3}=[1-9]',file)):
    listoffiles.append(os.path.splitext(file)[0])
```

Then in the listoffiles you have all your files names and you just have to use your expand like this :

```
expand("{repertory}{filename}{extension},
       repertory = "Resources/decompressed/",
       filename = listoffiles,
       extension = ".fastq")
```

Then everything should work perfectly.

Remember all python code in a snakefile will be executed at the beginning of the workflow before all rules and dags creation. So it can be powerful.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Pinchot! Your approach would certainly obtain the right file strings, however I would not be able to access them via wildcards I believe. Furthermore, the described problem is more or less a general one, and I would like to avoid having to declare explicit functions for all those cases.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look into bli's links?

Specifically, [this part of the documentation](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/additional_features.html#constraining-wildcards).

Here's a simple example of how I use it to generate a png, a pdf, or both:

```
rule all:
  input: expand("{graph}.png", graph=["dag", "rulegraph"])

rule dot_to_image:
    input: "{graph}.dot"
    output: "{graph}.{ext,(pdf|png)}"
    shell: "dot -T{wildcards.ext} -o {output} {input}"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think it probably is just not possible to execute regular expressions in expand. However I found a workaround. For two of the wildcards I found different ways to describe them ("read" and "index") and for the third one I prepared a function and used it as the input.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

###### WILDCARDS #####

## General descriptive parameters
read = (1,2)
index = list(range(1,9)) + list(range(11,32))

## Functions
def getDCinput(wildcards):
    read = wildcards.read
    index = wildcards.index
    path = wd + "Resources/raw/run1_lane1_read" + read + r"_index[0-9]??-[0-9]??=" + sample + ".fastq.gz"
    return(glob.glob(path))

##### RULES #####

### CONJUNCTION RULES ("all") ###
# PREANALYSIS #

rule all_decompress:
    input:
        expand("Resources/decompressed/read{read}_index{index}.fastq", read=read, index=index)

### TASK RULES ###
# FILE PREPARATION AND SMOOTHING #

# Decompress .gz zipped raw files
rule DECOMPRESS:
    input:
        getDCinput
    output:
        "Resources/decompressed/read{read}_index{index}.fastq"
    shell:
        "gzip -d -c {input} > {output}"
```